# Performance of Java TreeMap vs HashMap with sorted keys

Tags: java, performance, sorting, hashmap

I often have a situation in which I must place a large number of items in a Map, then retrieve them in a sorted order. This is done as separate operations; once the retrieval starts, no more items are added.

In this case, would it be more efficient to use a TreeMap (which AFAIK sorts on every put() operation), or use a HashMap and sort the list of keys?

Comment: You'd have to construct a meaningful benchmark for the two classes that implement the SortedMap interface: TreeMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap.  I'd prefer that to a guess or opinion on SO.  Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/lmdbjava/benchmarks/blob/master/results/20160710/README.md

Comment: Why do you need the HashMap if you only need to retrieve them in a sorted order? You just need a list/array

Comment: godlamp: Insertion is a multistage process. I'm reading data in from one source, creating objects and placing in the map. Then I read data from another source, and update the existing objects with this different data. The order is not relevant in these stages, but is only relevant when I'm iterating through the objects afterwards.